# Mongo db database design creation

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

It's my first experience with NoSQL. So I am very confused about its design creation. I read that `MongoDB` database contains `Document` , document contains `Collection` and collections contains `Fields`.
My Question is that If I want to create a DB and a table `User` and fields `Username` , `password`: 
**Collection = *User*** 
**Fields     = *Username and password*** 
Then what is the purpose of `Document` ??
Maybe this question is of a low standard but please consider it that it's my first experience with `NoSQL`.

Answer (score 2):

For a MongoDB structure, the document would be User, and inside the document you could have Fields or even documents depending on the need. And a collection is a group of documents.

[image]

I recomend you to read [JSON](http://json.org/) documentation and [MongoDB Data Modeling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/).

**Document:** A record in a MongoDB collection and the basic unit of data in MongoDB. Documents are analogous to JSON objects but exist in the database in a more type-rich format known as BSON.

**Collection:** A grouping of MongoDB documents. A collection is the equivalent of an RDBMS table. A collection exists within a single database. Collections do not enforce a schema. Documents within a collection can have different fields. Typically, all documents in a collection have a similar or related purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you familiar with relational databases, you can think of collections as tables(relations), documents as rows(tuples), fields as columns(attributes). Difference is that fields(attributes) assotiated with documents(tuples) not collections(relations). Hence schemalessness as collection does not put any constrains on documents it hold. And documents can contain other documents as fields, which violates normalization and doesn't have much sense in relational model as there's no attributes stored with nested tuple. Consider `Person` document vs row counterpart:

```
{ lastname: 'Average', firstname: 'Joe', address: { country: 'USA', city: 'NY' } }

+----------+-----------+---------+
| lastname | firstname |  adress |
+----------+-----------+---------+
| Average  |    Joe    | USA, NY |
+----------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: ok here is the confusion. is a document a group of collections or collection is a group of document?

Comment: is row is a collection of tables or table is group of rows?

Comment: I got the point , just need to clear one confusion please .. now `User` is `Document` and `Username and password` is Fields. what should be `Collection` in this case?

Comment: Think of documents which contain documents as de-normalized row in which we shove another tuple in single cell.

Comment: In table where each record represent user table called user. If it's not reserved word. Same applyies here. Collection is users. Can't made my mind with singular or plular. Tables should also named plural but it better for orm and sql to name them singular.

Comment: Document essantially nameless like row. It is it's container (collection/field) that gives it sense.